# What is a right way to fix bug and merge the changes to previous version and all next versions in git?

Tags: git, github

I'm a single developer with master, dev branch, and one or more feature branches (from dev) and bugfix branches (from master), which I'm always merge into master and also dev.

How should I properly solve the following situation?

- I have a master branch with a lot of commits,
- ...in next commit is set v3.0 tag,
- ...then again a set of commits and other tags (other versions),
- and then a commit with v5.0 tag.

In version 3.0 I found a small bug that I need to fix it in all version from 3.0 (inluded) and higher versions.

I proceeded as follows:

```
git clone .... cloned git to localhost

git checkout v3.0 checkout to v3.0 tag commit
```

then I made changes in source codes and then

```
git add . add changes to stack

git checkout -b bugfix checkout to new branch bugfix

git commit -m "My Bugfix ..." make commit
```

... so I moved the changes to this branch and checked out there and commit and now I don't know how those bugfix branch merge not to the end of the master branch but add them as a new commit just after the commit with the v3.0 tag.

```
commit1
commit2
commit3 tag v3.0
<== merge bugfix commit
commit4
commit5
```

Comment: Why should you fix your previous tags? After all, git is used to maintain history. If you fix previous versions, how will you know when the bug was actually fixed?

Comment: You need to bump version and tag it. Usually people create branches to monitor stable releases.

Comment: @Sabareesh In my case, it's private repos, and make bugfix versions 3.0.0, 3.0.1,... is not necessary for me. But OK, If I will make a new tag for each bugfix, for example like in my case, I need to make 3.0.1, 4.0.1, 5.0.1, how to make it most simple from one bugfix branch? Thx.

Comment: @0andriy Yes, it's also a way. I was thinking only, that one master branch will be most simple for single develoer, like in my case.

Comment: In published repository you may keep still one branch and many tags, but locally it's easier to have branch per stable version. In any case you may always to create a temporary anonymous branch (derived from the previous tag), do changes, tag with new version, push tag and kill the branch.

Comment: @0andriy but If I do this, I will update only one version, or...?. Is it possible to make branch from tag for example v3.0, fix the bug and merge the change with v3.0, v4.0 and v5.0? Thx..

Answer (score 0):

> so I moved the changes to this branch and checked out there and commit

perfect.

> and now I don't know how those bugfix branch merge not to the end of the master branch but add them as a new commit just after the commit with the v3.0 tag.

You don't. If you want to offer a completely alternate history where you fixed that bug before doing all the other work, you can rebase all that other work onto your fix and force-push the result, but

a) when you're preparing a patch series for publication it's *by far* better to just fix the bad commit and rebase on the corrected one, and

b) this isn't prepublication work, you're not editing for publication, you're publishing errata to a history that's out there, that people are relying on. If (*if*) you can casually let everyone know "hey, I had to rebase v3.0, sorry, refetch and rebase anything you did based on that or anything since then", then that's workable. For oopses you pick up soon enough, it's also much better than all alternatives.

v3.0 had a bug and you're on v5.0, so no, this isn't a vanishable oops. This is a bug that got out, you've identified and published the fix, now merge it to all the tips that need fixing.  To make the integration work easier, first merge from the current tips' common merge base, then merge from there to the individual tips.